# How to fix import private key in GPG?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, gnupg, file-encryption, openpgp

Since, I am new to gpg I wanted to generate a key pair. So I typed `gpg --full-gen-key` and inputted the following:

```
root@kali-linux:~# gpg --full-gen-key
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.35; Copyright (C) 2022 g10 Code GmbH
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Please select what kind of key you want:
   (1) RSA and RSA (default)
   (2) DSA and Elgamal
   (3) DSA (sign only)
   (4) RSA (sign only)
  (14) Existing key from card
Your selection? 1
RSA keys may be between 1024 and 4096 bits long.
What keysize do you want? (3072) 4096
Requested keysize is 4096 bits
Please specify how long the key should be valid.
         0 = key does not expire
      <n>  = key expires in n days
      <n>w = key expires in n weeks
      <n>m = key expires in n months
      <n>y = key expires in n years
Key is valid for? (0) 0
Key does not expire at all
Is this correct? (y/N)
...
Email address: example@example.com
Comment: Machine Test
You selected this USER-ID:
    "Machine Test (Machine Test) <example@example.com>"

Change (N)ame, (C)omment, (E)mail or (O)kay/(Q)uit? O
We need to generate a lot of random bytes. It is a good idea to perform
some other action (type on the keyboard, move the mouse, utilize the
disks) during the prime generation; this gives the random number
generator a better chance to gain enough entropy.
We need to generate a lot of random bytes. It is a good idea to perform
some other action (type on the keyboard, move the mouse, utilize the
disks) during the prime generation; this gives the random number
generator a better chance to gain enough entropy.
gpg: /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: directory '/root/.gnupg/openpgp-revocs.d' created
gpg: revocation certificate stored as '/root/.gnupg/openpgp-revocs.d/45C209A8503CDA6BAC24AE97EECFF3838F56DCDA.rev'
public and secret key created and signed.

pub   rsa4096 2022-06-10 [SC]
      45C209A8503CDA6BAC24AE97EECFF3838F56DCDA
uid                      Machine Test (Machine Test) <example@example.com>
sub   rsa4096 2022-06-10 [E]

root@kali-linux:/tmp/gpg# gpg --list-keys
/root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2022-06-10 [SC]
      45C209A8503CDA6BAC24AE97EECFF3838F56DCDA
uid           [ultimate] Machine Test (Machine Test) <example@example.com>
sub   rsa4096 2022-06-10 [E]

root@kali-linux:/tmp/gpg# gpg --armor --export 45C209A8503CDA6BAC24AE97EECFF3838F56DCDA > machinetest.asc
root@kali-linux:/tmp/gpg# gpg --armor --export-secret-keys 45C209A8503CDA6BAC24AE97EECFF3838F56DCDA > machinetest-private.asc
root@kali-linux:/tmp/gpg# rm .gnupg -r
rm: cannot remove '.gnupg': No such file or directory
root@kali-linux:/tmp/gpg# rm ~/.gnupg -r
root@kali-linux:/tmp/gpg# gpg --allow-secret-key-import --import machinetest-private.asc
gpg: directory '/root/.gnupg' created
gpg: keybox '/root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
gpg: /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key EECFF3838F56DCDA: public key "Machine Test (Machine Test) <example@example.com>" imported
gpg: key EECFF3838F56DCDA/EECFF3838F56DCDA: error sending to agent: No such file or directory
gpg: error building skey array: No such file or directory
gpg: error reading 'machinetest-private.asc': No such file or directory
gpg: import from 'machinetest-private.asc' failed: No such file or directory
gpg: Total number processed: 0
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg:       secret keys read: 1
root@kali-linux:/tmp/gpg#
root@kali-linux:/tmp/gpg# gpg --list-keys
/root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2022-06-10 [SC]
      45C209A8503CDA6BAC24AE97EECFF3838F56DCDA
uid           [ unknown] Machine Test (Machine Test) <example@example.com>
sub   rsa4096 2022-06-10 [E]

root@kali-linux:/tmp/gpg# gpg --list-secret-keys
```

So, my questions are:

- Why does it fail to import private key?

Basically I am trying to recreate a situation in which I have backed up my files and encrypted with my gpg private key. Now, I reinstalled the OS, downloaded the encrypted zip file and got machinetest-private.asc from my secure location. But it fails to import. Any idea why its doing so?

- Since my private key is password protected is it safe to store in cloud services or give it to a friend?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to import files that do not reside in your current directory. "No such file or directory" is usually self-explanatory. Either move (`cd`) to the desired directory or provide the full path along with file name. As far as I can tell this is not an issue with GPG but using Linux.

Comment: @Kate Are you sure? You can see he's in `/tmp/gpg` the whole time.

Comment: It could be that the **GPG agent** is confused as a result of deleting ~/.gnupg.  Note the trace: "error sending to agent". I would advise the OP to test the import on a completely different machine, and not the one where the key was created in the first place. The test would be more realistic. Suggestion: boot with Tails (an amnesic distro) to test the key import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced similar GPG bug. It actually can't find `$GNUPGHOME/private-keys-v1.d` folder and exits with `No such file or directory` error.

Manually creaing empty

```
~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d
```

folder solved the issue in my case.